# How can I combine JS files into one without errors

Tags: javascript, html

Below is a list of JS files I am running on my site. I want to combine them all in to one minified file. When I do so the page brings up common jquery errors. But all I have done is minified them and put them in the same file (in the same order).

When I keep them individually entered then there is no errors

```
jquery-1.8.3.min.js
modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js
bootstrap.js
script.js (custom js)
jquery.validate.js
bootstrap.notify.js
jquery.hoverintent.min.js
jquery.cookie.js
jquery.superfish.min.js
jquery.cycle2.min.js
respond.min.js  
jquery.magnific-popup.min.js
html5shiv-printshiv.min.js
```

Comment: Are you trying this for some performance gain? I think if the files are individual, browsers will get it by async calls, so that multiple files can be downloaded simultaniously (like the Download managers), if u put everything in one file, ultimately this is going to take time to download.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is a build manager. You can use something like [Bower](http://bower.io/) or [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/). If you want to roll your own build manager, this [blog post](http://blog.paracode.com/2012/02/15/build-mgmt-javascript-coffeescript/) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Like Bobby told you, you can use Grunt to work with some useful tools that allow you minify all your files.

Concretly, the plugin that could help you is **[contrib-uglify](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-uglify)**, made by the Grunt Team. If you want to use Grunt (and its tools), you can read the Getting Started to install Grunt, and the, follow the instructions to install contrib-uglify. Then, if you want to know how work uglify, you have everything that you need in the [Github repository](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify).

Grunt is very simple and interesting. I began to use it recently and I can say that it's very useful.

I hope that I have help you!